# Rigidbody2D stops when hits collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a player with Rigidbody2D and circle collider attached to it. The player collects coins which have circle collider. I move the player left and right. When it collects a coin, the coin destroys and player stops, so I have to touch again to continue moving left/right. So, how to collect coins without stopping player? Here is my code that moves rigidbody:

```
void TouchMove()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        float middle = Screen.width / 2;

        if (touch.position.x < middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }

        else if (touch.position.x > middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SetVelocityZero();
    }
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-playerSpeed, 0);
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, 0);
}

public void SetVelocityZero()
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coins should not be able to collide with any object especially the player.

Make the collider of the coin to be trigger then use `OnTriggerEnter2D` to detect when it touches the player in order to destroy the coinf instead of `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

[image]

Attach to your coin GameObject:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Player detected. Destroying this coin");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Or Attach to your player GameObject:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Coin detected. Destroying coin");
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```